# SlideToggle and li - repeated clicking reorder the list

Tags: jquery, animation, html-lists, slidetoggle

After clicking on any **li** item in the **ul** list - all items **show/hide** except the one clicked. I try to do nice animations using **slideToggle**. But with the repeatedly clicking on the same item list, change the order of the list.

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/rJHFW/)

HTML :

```
<ul class="imp">
    <li style="background: hotpink;">1</li>
    <li style="background: lightgreen;">2</li>
    <li style="background: lightblue;">3</li>
    <li style="background: bisque;">4</li>
    <li style="background: pink;">5</li>
    <li style="background: wheat;">6</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('li').click(function () {
    if ($(this).closest('ul').find('li').is(':hidden')) {
        $(this).prependTo(".imp").fadeIn("slow");
    } 
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').not($(this)).slideToggle("slow", function () {
        if ($(this).closest('ul').find('li').is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).prependTo(".imp");
        }
    });
});
```

CSS

```
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    height: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the `prependTo` method ?

It alters the DOM and that is why it is happening..

if you remove the two `prependTo` lines it will work as you want..

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/rJHFW/1/

---

And you could simplify all your code to just

```
$('li').click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/rJHFW/2/

---

**Update** (*after comment*)

You can do the prependint after the animation is complete

Here is some code to do it (*with some checks thrown in*)

```
$('li').click(function () {
    var self = $(this),
        siblings = self.siblings(),
        count = siblings.length,
        show = siblings.is(':hidden'),
        inprogress = siblings.is(':animated');

    // early break if an animation is still in progress
    if (inprogress) return;


    // slidetoggle 
    // and change position only after the animation is complete
    siblings.slideToggle('slow', function(){
        count--;
        if( count === 0 && !show){
            self.prependTo('.imp');
        }
    });
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/rJHFW/4/

Comment: Thank you for helping me... I know that prependTo is the reason, but I want to move selected item to the first position.

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas:

Try working with [$().stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/): http://jsfiddle.net/bPTZM/1/

```
$('li').click(function () {
    if ($(this).closest('ul').find('li').is(':hidden')) {
        $(this).prependTo(".imp").stop().fadeIn("slow");
    } 
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').not($(this)).stop().slideToggle("slow", function () {
        if ($(this).closest('ul').find('li').is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).prependTo(".imp");
        }
    });
});
```

Alternatively you could also prevent clicks while an animation is running: http://jsfiddle.net/bPTZM/2/

```
var animating = false;
$('li').click(function () {
    if(animating) return;
    else animating = true;

    if ($(this).closest('ul').find('li').is(':hidden')) {
        $(this).prependTo(".imp").fadeIn("slow");
    } 
    $(this).closest('ul').find('li').not($(this)).slideToggle("slow", function () {
        if ($(this).closest('ul').find('li').is(':hidden')) {
            $(this).prependTo(".imp");
        }
        animating = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts to help me, but... Maybe, I was not clear in question. But, try to click a few times - for example on number 4... you will see, that list is everytime disordered.

Comment: Okay sorry, then this was a simple misunderstanding. Good luck anyways!